# create a topbar shortcut to an .sh script

Tags: application-development, shortcuts, panel, top-bar

I want to be able to run a script with custom parameters via a shortcut in the top bar. On ubuntu 22.04.

I imagine it would look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylYbE.png)

How can I make something like that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.desktop` file (e.g. `myscript.desktop`) in your directory `~/.local/share/applications/` like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Type=Application
Name=* My Script *
Comment=A menu to call myscript.sh with various parameters
Icon=/home/your_user/.local/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/MyScript.png
Exec=/home/your_user/bin/myscript.sh
Path=/home/your_user/
Terminal=true
Keywords=MyScript
Actions=args1;x1;args2;x2;args3;x3;args4;x4;args5;x5

[Desktop Action args1]
Name=⯈myscript --args1
Exec=/home/your_user/bin/myscript.sh --args1

[Desktop Action x1]
Name=------
#Exec=.

[Desktop Action args2]
Name=⯈myscript --args2
Exec=/home/your_user/bin/myscript.sh --args2

[Desktop Action x2]
Name=------
#Exec=.

[Desktop Action args3]
Name=⯈myscript --args3
Exec=/home/your_user/bin/myscript.sh --args3

[Desktop Action x3]
Name=------
#Exec=.

[Desktop Action args4]
Name=⯈myscript --args4
Exec=/home/your_user/bin/myscript.sh --args4

[Desktop Action x4]
Name=------
#Exec=.

[Desktop Action args5]
Name=⯈myscript --args5
Exec=/home/your_user/bin/myscript.sh --args5

[Desktop Action x5]
Name=------
#Exec=.
```

### Some Notes:

- The "desktop" specification does not allow to use `~` or shell environment variables like `$HOME` or relative paths.
- The actions `x1` .. `x5` are used as visual separators. Note that there is no `Exec=` line and the `Name=` line consists of dashes (you can change it to something better).
- You can create a special icon in the directory specified at line `Icon=`.
- The "default" action would be to call the script with no parameters; see the *first* line starting with `Exec=`. You can change this line or you can leave it like this and in this case you can design your script so that it will show (for example) a text based menu which will be displayed inside a "terminal" window.
- The `Name=` lines can be anything you like; I tried to use a fancy character (`⯈`) at the start of some of them.
- After you create the `desktop` file, you can access it like any GNOME application and you can "pin" it to your "top bar".

See also [this](https://developer-old.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/).